# How to encode URI with blank space in VOS isql service?

Tags: encoding, uri, sparql, whitespace, virtuoso

As we write SPARQL in Virtuoso, it is easy to escape a space within an URI by coding the space with `%20`. However, when I run the same query on Virtuoso isql service, the escape fails. Here is my query:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wdno: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/novalue/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
#Items with specific picture
#Note that URL of the filename must be URL encoded.
#added before 2016-10
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE
{
?item wdt:P18 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Flag%20of%20the%20Netherlands.svg>
OPTIONAL{?item rdfs:label ?en . FILTER(LANG(?en) = "en")}
    BIND(str(COALESCE(?en,strafter(str(?item),"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/"))) AS ?itemLabel)
}
LIMIT 100
```

The error says:

> *** Error 37000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 22: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 18: syntax error at '<' before 'http:' at
>   line 0 of Top-Level:
>
> ```
> SPARQL PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
> PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
> PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
> PREFIX wdno: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/novalue/>
> PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
> PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
> PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
> PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
> PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
> PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
> #Items with specific picture
> #Note that URL of the filename must be URL encoded.
> #added before 2016-10
> SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
> WHERE
> {
> ?item wdt:P18 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Flag of the Netherlands.svg>
> OPTIONAL{?item rdfs:label ?en . FILTER(LANG(?en) = "en")}
>   BIND(str(COALESCE(?en,strafter(str(?item),"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/"))) AS ?itemLabel)
> }
> LIMIT 100
> ```

Isql is not being understood with the `%20` because it prints the resource (URI) with white space.

Comment: Have you tried `%2520`, `+` and `\ `?

Comment: with%2520 worked well. Thank you @StanislavKralin

Comment: Inspired by https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/whitespace-in-uris :-).

Comment: It helps to know what version of Virtuoso you are running (first paragraph of output from `virtuoso-t -?` or `virtuoso-iodbc-t -?`). Also, did you encounter this issue with the command-line `isql`. or with the browser-based iSQL tool?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a URI with embedded whitespace. All whitespace characters *must* be percent-encoded to construct a valid URI. See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A).