# How Can I execute SPARQL1.1 queries containing '+', '?' character in property path using ISQL on Virtuoso?

Tags: character-encoding, sparql, virtuoso

I need to run some SPARQL 1.1 queries, but I have problems with some characters on property paths.

```
SELECT ?item ?other
WHERE {
    ?item  wdt:P279+ wd:Q37144 .   # cartridges
    ?item  wdt:P144    ?other  .   # if the cartridge is based on another
}
```

It does not give an error, but it does not deliver results. The problem is the character `+`,  because changing `wdt:P279+` to `wdt:P279/wdt:P279*` works correctly. Similarly, the symbol `?`. In this case it does deliver results, but it logs error `More than 0 parameters, ignoring all the rest of the statement SPARQL`

I have tried with `\+`, `\\+`, `\002B`, `\053`, etc.

Comment: See comments to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49418156/7879193 Perhaps you should use `%253F` for `?` and `%252B` for `+`.

Comment: Please try your query through the browser-based iSQL and through the browser-based SPARQL endpoint. Please also provide complete version strings for Virtuoso (output of `virtuoso-t -?`), iSQL (output of `isql -?`). My guess is that you're seeing this happen in the command-line iSQL, which may need some additional tweaks to handle the Property Path characters when executing SPASQL a/k/a SPARQL-in-SQL, queries. I believe the browser-based tool handles all these at this point. The above details will help confirm my guess, so I can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your query with my own local command-line iSQL `07.20.3217` built `2017-09-06` and installed with Virtuoso 8.1 (Enterprise Edition).

iSQL had no complaints about the `+` nor `*`, and delivered good results for both, but I do see a complaint about the `?` (which does not occur in the browser-based iSQL).

Thus, I think that an updated iSQL will get you past the `+` issue.

It would be helpful if you could [log an issue on the github project](http://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) about the `?`.